# How to preprocess the HTML content using Jquery "ON"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have very simple jQuery Accordion, it is working fine, now the issues are if i load the accordion content dynamically either from DB or from JSON to page, It is not working, because there is no information to DOM to understand the class or ID which newly injected. so i am trying to use Jquery ON instead live or delegate to capture the injected elements. my sample code is..

```
jQuery("#header").on("click", function () {
 .... my accordion code here
});
```

but jquery "on" will trigger on any event like click or something, so how to process the accordion html content to keep open in initial level and do further click.

How is this possible? i couldn't fine any solution

Comment: Could you paste some html too? Do you just want a normal accordian?

Comment: i do not want any accordion code, pls check my accordion code here http://www.stemkoski.com/downloads/jquery-accordion-menu-update/example.htm

Comment: it's really hard to understand your question. You describing a problem with `jQuery.on` which makes no sense (`"on" will fire on any event like click or something`). I took a look at your JS code and I think you should use `jQuery.on` instead of `jQuery.click` like this: `$('.accordionButton').on({click: function() { /* whatever * / }, mouseover: function() { /* */ } });` if you want to create accordion blocks dynamically.

Comment: no no, my question is not about accordion on or off, my question about jquery on  jQuery("#id").on("",.....   i used "on" instead of "live"

Comment: Oookkkkaaay... so, what is the problem using `on` instead of `live`? `$('#id').on('click', function(){})` will work the same as `$('#id').live('click', function(){})` But I'd encourage you to use `on` because `live` will propagate triggered event to DOM root node anyway and using `live` you can stop event bubbling to the root node which is `on`'s advantage over `live`.

Comment: i have updated my question for better clarity

Comment: @Nemoden, yes it is correct, but how it is going to preprocess the content without that click event, if any event like "ready" instead of "click" in on will solve the issues. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/RMBpt/

What i added:

```
var isActive = $(this).is('.on');
if(!isActive) { .. if active, it shouldn't collapse? }

//First element should be active, needs to be after the hide()
$('.accordionButton:first').addClass('on').next().slideDown('normal');
```

---

Try using it like this:

```
$("#wrapper").on("click", ".accordionButton", function(event){
    //Your accordian code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks Marco, you made me that accordion little more flexible. i will update, but my real problem on "on"

Comment: I tried your code, it is always opening first accordion not the one i am clicking, and initially everything kept open, i tried same in jsfiddle also, it is getting the same result

Comment: Im having a really hard time understanding what you are injecting with JSON/DB data. Do you have a live soloution you could show?

Comment: It is very simple, consider a html code which you are having in your jsfiddle for this example, html code that i am preparing and injecting to <div id="wrapper"> </div> because those items are not loaded when page loaded, hope this will help

Comment: the meaning of dynamic means that i am making whenever it is required that will not available in page load or dom ready.

Comment: Then give each "button" a seperate class, when you fire the ajax call, you save the active button class, insert JSON/DB, make the recored active button active. The code you produced have nothing todo with any call - so can't recreate it.